# Concatenate or Infer string in Typescript / GraphQL

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

### Problem

Trying to infer the return type of several **graphQL** queries in **TypeScript**.  The main issue is that the queries return the objects wrapped in the names of the queries.  So a query for users could be named `listUsers`, and return `User[]`; however, in GraphQL/Apollo, it returns `Record<'listUsers', User[]>`.  I'm wondering how I can infer the `'list${queryName}'` key with TypeScript.

### Example Request

```js
const getUsers = () => apolloClient.query<Record<'listUsers', User[]>>({
  query: gql`
    query {
      listUsers {
        ...UserFragment
      }
    }
    ${USER_FRAGMENT}
  `
})
```

### What I Want

I want to create a function to return these respective methods: list, details, create, update, delete.  I wondered if it were possible to pass a `string` for the GraphQL type, and a type for the return type.  Something like this:

```js
const createResource = <T, K extends string>(name: K, fragment: string) => ({
  list() {
    // I want to concatenate 'list' and `name`, but I don't think I can!
    return apolloClient.query<Record<`list${name}s`, T[]>>({
      query: gql`
        query {
          list${name}s {
            ...${name}Fragment
          }
        }
        ${fragment}
      `
    })
  },
  // more methods here for `create`, `update`, `delete`, using the same name and fragment...
})
```

### The Ask

Is there a way to create a type like this?

```
Record<`list${name}`, T[]>
```

If not (and I assume there is not), what's a better solution to this problem?  I really do not want to have to copy-paste all these methods for each model.  I also do not want to have to reduce them all to:

```
Record<string, T[]>
```

And then have to guess at what the key is:

```js
const userReq = await getUsers()

userReq.data.listUsers // ??? is this right?
```

Comment: Not possible to concatenate strings in the type system.

Comment: If you can refactor so that you call a method or property named `data.list.users` instead of `data.listUsers` you can write typings.  (Of course this might require that you wrap whatever's currently generating the concatenated string.)  Otherwise this is just outside of what the TS type system can do for you.

Comment: I assumed there is not a way to concatenate strings for types; but is there a better solution, where I wouldn't have to copy-paste a bunch of repetitive functions for these methods?

Comment: A solution here is to use GraphQL aliases; question appears closed, and marked as a duplicate, so no one could answer this:
gql` query {
    results: list${name}s {
    }
  }`.
Now the query can be: query<Record<'results', User[]>>.